# jquery parse string to array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Server return me array as strig:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3286187
            [date] => 2019-08-20 09:07:05
            [ipaddr] => 
            [login] => 184021
            [type] => ����������� ���������
            [description] => ����������� ��������� 3286186
            [support] => tikhonenko
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3286186
            [date] => 2019-08-19 16:06:16
            [ipaddr] => 13.0.43.20
            [login] => 184021
            [type] => ���������� ���������
            [description] => 3

            [support] => t
        )
```

How to translate this data into an object?

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                // make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
                // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
                url: './?module=ajax&mode=filter',
                data,
                success: function (msg) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                    console.log(obj.toString())

                }
            });
```

When I try console.log, return nothing.
How to convert this data to an object? They have no header json.

Browser messsage:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data

Comment: That appears to be just a `print_r` output? That function is for debugging purposes, your server should not respond with such a format to begin with, if _transporting_ data is the purpose. Are you in control of the server side? If so, this should be changed to return JSON to begin with.

Comment: `parseJSON` will only work on a string containing real json data, which isn't what you actually get. Btw, I'm not sure what the `data` is doing in the Ajax request? If you want to pass some parameters, it should be `data: {foo: 'bar', ...}`, not just `data,`. If you don't want to pass any data, just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP is not giving you a string to run `$.parseJSON` on. It looks like you are given a `print_r` ("human-readable information about a variable") of an array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php.

If there is a `print_r($something);` in your PHP, you should change that to `echo json_decode($something);`. You will then get the array in JSON format. Therefor, you can just change this:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
console.log(obj.toString())
```

To:

```
console.log(msg);
```

Also, remove `data,` in your Javascript if you're not sending any data, or change it to `data: data,` if `data` is a variable that you have declared somewhere outside `$.ajax()`.

Side note: as of jQuery 3.0, `$.parseJSON` is deprecated: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/.